# In jQuery, what happens when you have two .children() functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, what happens when you have two .children() functions?

```
 var area = image.canvas.children('.image-pinpoint-edit').children('.image-pinpoint-edit-area');
```

Is it redundant? cant you just do `image.canvas.children('image-pinpoint-edit-area')` to get the inner children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var area = image.canvas.children('.image-pinpoint-edit').children('.image-pinpoint-edit-area');
```

this is not redundant...

you are getting the children of the children...

1 level <--- `image.canvas`

2 level <----- `.children('.image-pinpoint-edit')`

3 level <----- `.children('.image-pinpoint-edit-area').children('.image-pinpoint-edit-area')`

if you wishes to find `'image-pinpoint-edit-area'`

use `.find()`

```
image.canvas.find('.image-pinpoint-edit-area');    
// this this will search all its children, grand children, grand grand children, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image.canvas.find('image-pinpoint-edit-area')` - this will look for the closer element that matches given selector(no matter on which level it exists), `.children` looks only for elements that are *direct* children of given selector.

edit:
Your way to do this by .children().children() is also fine, I'm not sure what is faster (.children().children() or .find()) but your code should work!

Answer (score 0):

It is [possible for humans to do this](http://www.thisislondon.co.uk/news/article-23480767-pictured-inside-the-cellar-where-father-locked-daughter-for-24-years-and-repeatedly-raped-her.do), but DOM elements can't be both the parent and grandparent of a given element.